# Attribute Error: 'function' object has no attribute 'randint'

Tags: python, django, random

I'm having trouble with using the random module in my Django app. When I open up a path that should display a random number, I get an error that says: 'function' object has no attribute 'randint'.

I've looked this error up, and most people say that this error is because there is a stray random.py file floating around somewhere. [Proof there's only one random.py file in my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44ESS.png), and it is definitely the one that came with the python install. I'm 100% certain, because I uninstalled python 3.8.3 and reinstalled it twice.
Here are my imports:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django import forms


from . import util
import os, re, random
```

Here's the code in my views.py file that is calling random.randomint.

```
def entry(request, title):
    entry = util.get_entry(title)
    randomNum = random.randint(0, 10)
    return render(
            request,
            "encyclopedia/entry.html",
            {"entry": entry, "randomNum": randomNum},
        )
```

Then I have an HTML file that displays `{{ randomNum }}`. When that template gets loaded, I get  [this error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkYUu.png). I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us your imports!

Comment: @KlausD., thanks for the reminder! I totally thought I had included them. Just edited.

Comment: Does search of `random =`, `def random` or `class random` find something?

Comment: Your error indicates a bad import (`from random import random` instead of just `import random`) or that you overwrote the import with another function called `random`.

Comment: It's not `from random import random` or `from random import *`. That would give a [different error message](https://ideone.com/lKvv5O), since `random.random` is actually a method of a hidden `random.Random` instance.

Comment: what does print(random) give you

Comment: Please post the traceback with the exact message and failing line.

Comment: Just before the fail, you could `import random`. If it starts working (and perhaps fails somewhere else where different code is calling `random()`) you'll know what you are looking for.

Comment: @KlausD. that was exactly it! Well, not a function, but a URL path

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out!!!! It's not that I had a file called random.py, but I did have a view path called  path("random", views.random, name="random"). I deleted that and now randomint works!

Edit: Actually it wasn't the URL path, I also had a view in views.py called random. That was the problem.

Comment: Interesting. Add that to the list of non-obvious things to look for.

Comment: You had a view/function named “random” in your views file. This was overriding the import...